# jquery Centering a div Y axis bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got some divs that I would like to center. I got this code in order to do that:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    this.show(800);
    return this;
}
```

but the problem is, when the page is scrollable from first place, the div isn't centered properly and it shows centered according to the WHOLE page, not the part of the screen that the user can actually see.

Any idea how to fix it?

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cK3XB/

Comment: please provide the html code as well. create a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

try this then .

```
jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", ($(window).outerHeight() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
    this.css("left", ($(window).outerWidth() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
    this.show(800);
    return this;
}
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/xxsxk

Comment: bet money that you have it in a div that isnt positioned relatively :)

Comment: well, the div parent is "body" :o

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to something else in my code :o?
I checked something. When the page loaded, i called for $(window).outerHeight() and alerted out the output it was equals to the viewport, but when the function cold it, it was equals to the WHOLE document height

Comment: please try to provide jsfiddle witht he problem , or else no one can help :/

Comment: Guess I can't be helped :c